# What the relationship between kernel tarball in ftp.kernel.org and git tree in git.kernel.org?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am interested in linux kernel development process. My question is in titile.

I visited git.kernel.org. This gitweb interface can generate tarball by snapshot. Does the maintainer grab the balls and put them on ftp.kernel.org? maybe too naive

Answer (score 1):

Developers use [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) to get the latest Linux kernel and work on it.

For more details on the development process of Linux kernel, please read the official documents: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/development-process/